# Support for "hideUnchangedRegions" in monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, monaco-editor

As the support for hideUnchangedRegions is added for vs code editor and being used, Is this supported in monaco editor.

i tried setting this up here
[Playground link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.43.0#XQAAAAIzDQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscxO9s1JVciAJM8XEuX7Os378jBGtVLkr6ryuhqvky-XZ9Sy0vyFSI1m9lYQpwqOsaKmhydYWIo-9hGbv_4wlPIPgtqhTkCaP_3UoGmxzcp_dpGz6gCIgsALZ1pAD5zLJA88IU-UqH2D63t9rskFjH-YfluvZOsF8-ptIQNHo__6Vpv18NWLYay4B-13hhjHwaT_Vjj2KPLMVX1G9gF_gazFnxRML4ZfTufmz7knpsx-zvjJLpCMAQuqp3MbUGNoxWgNeZv1sp_551ZW9vpavATgsWhFcDd3BvTQQR6A53HBZO8I9Bb3ks0-Ox9xzWTxZiXTx5oosroF1BnB_Y29WN2Ektc6w9TrO8dVtqVUGkD4GHZH6WN9-4Mv1U0_j8Rl_eWF7UE08RhFsFj8r5xrPmF7ZTkExi32a6BLV-FLQss4DF3K1cUe5jvmfZ63ScrL5v4OOkoR-5Crgi8VWvuAKRZ5dTZuA_LmuPz-8gUbn7i8Qb_f_aJKFyztiBc33xnSE4q9mpuBrwLr34S-YS6iIZjYlwkfohYYc3PitUYMEWWm625J7S6-L7gdb5sZTK0gFohoMYUq2mu5jTnAUMaL4S7l_Z4xu6DtTg1eMOEvlO-GB9ZjnyYsLO1s_4IV2aDmTkkuoGWrY-_dwXMGLo9LH_2H1XJw7RUFNFXESxgGVI1k_A2qijYkf4XC6d7igG1LwgvPnLU9riMkTWuFeaSRZ6R64AbiSHqYSp6VCTDZWu7dOE9oeo0wzYvVDnnI8UCFD4dMLA8fNK05yGBqorGTYGBaFl6POUVanHwNbXtvsGq5no2D6LLI0MWg6Fx-I7odGkLcPOWEF6Qse6Moof-rxHSNwY1OWQY29CjcPnsoCK3HL6TP0un5qQZz2AS0q0ZQFz2FopSlnCr-u3FdJqSG4gIkCfYnSJ8VbYUMnJ4mBqzatPd8C-BiLw0ZvG2UZFYJi3P-87q6xUg7awAJMEXIQ2CjYAYsViMcMoY_KKwj8IqpnMdoMmdI0EgU3cCR4Eu6nDPXgFblVLTUrhdla6g2gNXaKq8HqfBLMG3195k8c-9dZT0s68CpFdVUL54saJfYXiivRyePkQyz5gmBPDjkBFHnSoQMQ0LF6MABelArAnSkEH0OlXMxdZUDAEWYyShU6XFxjfuJiYkiflXnFcWu95928S4H4t5Zs4oYKkZ3jvZEyneFKTLROt04s0g3JrkJBdYqujs_pLlTBZ5UeXut1WULq-u1FxsrU7Vykb_uztmEJWpSN4zpq_q6ZSouWE9hRgXtSL3_-qVTBg)

Any help would be suggested,
The expected behaviour is as follow
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_collapsed-unchanged-code-headers

What i tried - [Playground link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.43.0#XQAAAAIzDQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscxO9s1JVciAJM8XEuX7Os378jBGtVLkr6ryuhqvky-XZ9Sy0vyFSI1m9lYQpwqOsaKmhydYWIo-9hGbv_4wlPIPgtqhTkCaP_3UoGmxzcp_dpGz6gCIgsALZ1pAD5zLJA88IU-UqH2D63t9rskFjH-YfluvZOsF8-ptIQNHo__6Vpv18NWLYay4B-13hhjHwaT_Vjj2KPLMVX1G9gF_gazFnxRML4ZfTufmz7knpsx-zvjJLpCMAQuqp3MbUGNoxWgNeZv1sp_551ZW9vpavATgsWhFcDd3BvTQQR6A53HBZO8I9Bb3ks0-Ox9xzWTxZiXTx5oosroF1BnB_Y29WN2Ektc6w9TrO8dVtqVUGkD4GHZH6WN9-4Mv1U0_j8Rl_eWF7UE08RhFsFj8r5xrPmF7ZTkExi32a6BLV-FLQss4DF3K1cUe5jvmfZ63ScrL5v4OOkoR-5Crgi8VWvuAKRZ5dTZuA_LmuPz-8gUbn7i8Qb_f_aJKFyztiBc33xnSE4q9mpuBrwLr34S-YS6iIZjYlwkfohYYc3PitUYMEWWm625J7S6-L7gdb5sZTK0gFohoMYUq2mu5jTnAUMaL4S7l_Z4xu6DtTg1eMOEvlO-GB9ZjnyYsLO1s_4IV2aDmTkkuoGWrY-_dwXMGLo9LH_2H1XJw7RUFNFXESxgGVI1k_A2qijYkf4XC6d7igG1LwgvPnLU9riMkTWuFeaSRZ6R64AbiSHqYSp6VCTDZWu7dOE9oeo0wzYvVDnnI8UCFD4dMLA8fNK05yGBqorGTYGBaFl6POUVanHwNbXtvsGq5no2D6LLI0MWg6Fx-I7odGkLcPOWEF6Qse6Moof-rxHSNwY1OWQY29CjcPnsoCK3HL6TP0un5qQZz2AS0q0ZQFz2FopSlnCr-u3FdJqSG4gIkCfYnSJ8VbYUMnJ4mBqzatPd8C-BiLw0ZvG2UZFYJi3P-87q6xUg7awAJMEXIQ2CjYAYsViMcMoY_KKwj8IqpnMdoMmdI0EgU3cCR4Eu6nDPXgFblVLTUrhdla6g2gNXaKq8HqfBLMG3195k8c-9dZT0s68CpFdVUL54saJfYXiivRyePkQyz5gmBPDjkBFHnSoQMQ0LF6MABelArAnSkEH0OlXMxdZUDAEWYyShU6XFxjfuJiYkiflXnFcWu95928S4H4t5Zs4oYKkZ3jvZEyneFKTLROt04s0g3JrkJBdYqujs_pLlTBZ5UeXut1WULq-u1FxsrU7Vykb_uztmEJWpSN4zpq_q6ZSouWE9hRgXtSL3_-qVTBg)